# SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert() caught as an exception when script run by FormSubmit; Fine when run interactively

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

The below is the code that despite the `ui.alert("Some message")` code being run only when `SpreadsheetApp.getUi()` can get the UI (when run interactively) fails with error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'alert' of undefined at sendEmails(E-mail form submissions:76:32)`

```
var DisplayAlerts = 0

// See if getUi will load; If not, we are likely not running this script interactively, so disable prompts
try
{
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
}
catch(err)
{
  DisplayAlerts = 1
}

if(DisplayAlerts){ui.alert("E-mail(s) sent");}
```

The script at https://xfanatical.com/blog/how-to-edit-google-forms-responses-in-the-spreadsheet/ utilise `SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert()` and runs interactively (producing the prompt at line 119) and via formsubmit trigger. What is the difference in that script to my login above? What do I need to do to not have two different scripts doing the same thing bar popping up alerts when running interactively?

Comment: Please add a [mcve]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to invoke SpreadsheetApp.getUi() via onFormSubmit in google app script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28290314/is-it-possible-to-invoke-spreadsheetapp-getui-via-onformsubmit-in-google-app-s)

Comment: @Rubén - Please see my comments on your below answer. Please put the code provided into Google Sheets code editor, attach a event, and run it. You should see the same error I just confirmed I get with the above instructions.

Comment: As I mentioned previously, please add a [mcve].

Comment: @Rubén - The above example IS complete, mininal and reproducible. Repeating the same language doesn't let others understand how what they have provided is not what you keep on asking for.

Answer (score 1):

I found that if run it this way:

```
var DisplayAlerts =true;
try{
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
}
catch(err) {
  DisplayAlerts = false;
}
if(DisplayAlerts){ui.alert("E-mail(s) sent");}
```

It doesn't get the alert on the formSubmit because it's opening up a Spreadsheet instance on the server which does have any UI.  And when I run another script from the script editor the alert fires correctly because it runs every time you run a function and I opened the container spreadsheet so it has a UI.

So I think the problem is that you have your 0 and 1 or true and false reversed.